# How to detect a song playing by iPod

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, ipod

Is it possible programmatically find out a song details of iPod library if my app allows playing background iPod music? 
some like:

```
start "My app"
if (iPod music playing)
{
song.details == playing.music.details"
}
```

I don't even have no idea how to determinate if is any song is playing by iPod.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It kinda easy:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]];

NSLog(@"Playing %@", [[musicPlayer nowPlayingItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist]);
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [Media Player Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html):

> "This framework...gives your
>   application access to the iPod
>   library."

Comment: I haven't thought it is that easy. :o) tnx