# pause ipod when playing voice from our apps, and resume after that

Tags: xcode, audio, ipod, voice, resume

I would like to make an application that prompt a voice. the scenario is like this:
1. ipod playing music
2. user start my apps
3. my apps is deciding to prompt a voice
4. ipod music become MUTE or SOFTER VOICE
5. my apps prompt a voice until finish
6. ipod music RESUME to original volume

any idea?

Comment: it is actually kinda easy. i found the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138247/app-which-detect-a-song-playing-by-ipod-in-background . we can get the instance of ipod the code should be like this: [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] pause];
//do whatever you want
[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] play];

Answer (score 0):

it is actually kinda easy. i found the answer from stackoverflow.com/questions/4138247/… . we can get the instance of ipod the code should be like this: [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] pause]; //do whatever you want [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] play];